# How can I make this regex?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm sorry for being annoying and asking other people to do this for me, but I have been trying for a while now and can't seem to get a working one. This is what it needs to allow:

- Lower case letters
- Upper case letters
- Apostrophes (`'`)
- Dashes (`-`)

It doesn't matter what order these come in for the string that will be rejected as long as it doesn't contain anything but the above characters. It is for objective-c if that affects anything in regex expressions.

```
NSString *nameRegEx = @"^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+$";
NSPredicate *firstTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegEx];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the "upper & lower-case letters, dash and apostrophe" part of the regex, try :--

```
[a-zA-Z'\\-]
```

You need to escape the - dash, if you're not going to depend on it being in certain syntactic positions in the [] character-class.

In Java, we'd need to use \\ double-backslashes -- a single-backslash would escape a control-character into the compiler, so we need a double-backslash to get a \ single backslash past the compiler to act as an escape in the regex. It may well be similar for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its more of upper and/or lower and/or apostraphy and/or dash

Comment: Which is what such a character class matches (one character thereof). You understand the * or + to put after it already, I assume.

Comment: The dash doesn't need escaping if it is at the end of a character class.